# JQUERY/JavaScript - RegEx everything after and including 3rd occurrence of character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to find some assistance in parsing out and replacing everything after (and including) the 3rd occurrence of a character with some text.

Here is an example of what I need accomplished:

Before:
Bob,Jones,Suzy,Amy,Cindy,Jimmy

After:
Bob,Jones,Suzy...

Ive gotten thus far:

```
var theString = ('Bob,Jones,Suzy,Amy,Cindy,Jimmy');
theString = theString.replace('', '...');
```

Comment: So you want to capture  up to three repetitions of an alphanumeric string followed by a comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `split + slice + join`:

```
var s = 'Bob,Jones,Suzy,Amy,Cindy,Jimmy'
var r = s.split(',').slice(0,3).join(',')
//=> "Bob,Jones,Suzy"
```